# Uniswap permit token

Tags: uniswap

In Uniswap, the permit function is used by the LP token when removing liquidity, it is not used for a regular token swap.

Could anybody explain it to me in more detail?
What happened when removing liquidity if there's no permit function?

Comment: What version of Uniswap? v2, v3? On what chain? Could you share a transaction hash?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg I meant on Uniswap v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permit function is similar to the approve function. Both of these functions involve the owner of a token giving permission to an address to spend some of the owners tokens.

The only difference is the following: With the approve function you need to submit the transaction onto the blockchain yourself. With the permit function you just sign the transaction with your wallet and then someone else (like Uniswap) can submit the transaction onto the blockchain for you (saving you gas and having to do two blockchain transactions).

The permit function is designed to give you a more frictionless user experience and enable gas-less transactions. However it's not widely adopted yet so you might see it in some places but not others.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I still have a problem understanding this. Looking at V2 code and I see it's a function that in the end calls approve, so wondering how can it call and change the state of the chain with just signature?

Comment: @Blissful The idea is that YOU create the signature with your wallet which doesnt require a transaction. You give the signature to someone else who can call the permit function and they use your signature to perform the transaction that you authorised.

Comment: @CathalMF where is the signature stored I wonder? Is it stored in UNI contracts and used in the future or is it stored in my wallet, auto-submitted when I again interact with UNI? how does flow work?

Comment: The signature is stored offline wherever you want. It could even be hand written on a piece of paper. The address of the signer can be recovered from the signature in a smart contract and compared to the data to validate it. This will be done by whatever contract accepts a signature as an input.